# apply filter on a function in python

Tags: python, function, filter

I am getting an unexpected output when I execute the following python code.
Iam new at python.

```
def foo(n):
    return n+2;
print (filter(foo,[1,2]))
```

i was expecting output as :-

```
[3,4]
```

but Iam getting output as:-

```
[1,2]
```

please help me solve this.

Comment: Wrong function. You want `map`, not `filter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described is `map` and not `filter`.

```
def foo(n):
    return n+2;
print (map(foo,[1,2]))
```

Prints out

```
[3,4]
```

Comment: so you mean to say filter returns the original values after checking if it is true or not??

Comment: `filter` retains the values in the list that pass `foo`. e.g. `def foo(n): return n>=2` `print(filter(foo,[1,2]))` will give `[2]`.

Comment: ...i got it. Thank you so much.